# Symfony Api Rest which validator process

Tags: php, json, symfony, validation

My question concerns various process of json payload validations.
I have recensed : 
- deserialization on a model, calling validator service and validate the hydrated object.
- using FormType (even if there are no forms...just json feeds) and validate the form builder after injecting $datas.

Which one do you prefer ?
Have you a better solution ? Such as maybe a middleware (unique bundle ou app that deals with all in/out-coming payloads - request/response)

Thank You

Comment: For me the best choice is the entity hydratation by form
So you have dynamically the validation process call on your hydrated entity.
The error handling is already present etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I validate/deserialize with the native listeners/tools `FOSRestBundle` provides.

Making use of the bundle you can have native form-validation  ... or  automatically deserialized and validated models plus a list of validation errors injected as controller arguments.

```
# app/config/config.yml 

# You need SensioFrameworkExtraBundle for body converters to work
sensio_framework_extra:
  request: { converters: true }

fos_rest:
  zone:
    - path: '^/api/(.*)+$'
  # [..]
  body_listener:
    enabled: true
    default_format: json
    decoders:
      json: fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform

  # automatically injects query parameters into controller Actions
  # see @FOSRest\QueryParam in the example below
  param_fetcher_listener: force

  # https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html
  body_converter:
    enabled: true
    validate: true
    validation_errors_argument: validationErrors
```

The body **converter** can deserialize and validate models automatically for you (without using any forms or manual steps). Example:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter(
 *   "post", 
 *   converter = "fos_rest.request_body",
 *   options = {
 *     "validator" = {
 *       "groups" = {
 *         "validation-group-one",
 *         "validation-group-two",
 *       }
 *     },
 *     "deserializationContext" = {
 *       "groups" = { 
 *         "serializer-group-one",
 *         "serializer-group-two"
 *       }, 
 *       "version"="1.0"
 *     }
 *   }
 * )
 */
public function putPostAction(Post $post, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{ 
    if (!empty($validationErrors)) {
        // return some 4xx reponse
    }
    // Do something with your deserialized and valid Post model
```

The bundle can serialize forms (and form-errors) to JSON, too.

i.e. a form with invalid fields will be rendered as:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Validation Failed",
    "errors": {
        "errors": [
            "This is a global form error."
        ],
        "children": {
            "oldPassword": {
                "errors": [
                    "The old password is not correct."
                ]
            },
            "newPassword": [],
            "submit": []
        }
    }
}
```

`FOSRestBundle` provides a request **body listener** that automatically decodes `Content-Type: application/json` to `Content: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` within the `Request` object so you can bind the request to the form with `handleRequest` as you'd do with normal HTML forms.

Quick tip: if you just want to validate your data asynchronously ... you can send the request with a query param (`?validate=true` in the following example) and return an early response with HTTP 200 (OK) / 202 (Accepted) before performing any business logic.

The following example shows an endpoint that accepts requests of the form:

```
{
    "oldPassword": "xxxxxxx",
    "newPassword": "yyyyyyy"
}
```

Corresponding controller action:

```
/**
 * @FOSRest\Route(
 *   "/profile/change-password",
 *   name="api_put_password",
 *   methods={
 *     Request::METHOD_PUT
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @FOSRest\QueryParam(
 *   name="validate",
 *   allowBlank=false,
 *   default="false",
 *   strict=true,
 *   nullable=true,
 *   requirements="^(true|false)$"
 * )
 */
public function putPasswordAction(Request $request, string $validate = 'false')
{
    $validate = filter_var($validate, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);

    $form = $this->formFactory->createNamed(null, ChangePasswordType::class, null, [
        'action' => $this->router->generateUrl('api_put_password'),
        'method' => $request->getMethod(),
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        $view = new View();
        $view->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        $view->setData($form);

        return $view;
    }

    if ($validate) {
        $view = new View();
        $responseCode = Response::HTTP_ACCEPTED;
        $view->setStatusCode($responseCode);
        $view->setData([
            'code'  => $responseCode,
            'message' => 'Data is valid.',
            'data' => null
        ]);

        return $view;
    }

    $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    /** @var PasswordChangeRequest $passwordChangeRequest */
    $passwordChangeRequest = $form->getData();
    $user->setPassword($this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $passwordChangeRequest->getNewPassword()));
    $this->userManager->persist($user);

    $view = new View();
    $view->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $view->setData([
        'code'  => Response::HTTP_OK,
        'message' => 'Password changed successfully.',
        'data' => $user
    ]);

    $context = new Context();
    $context->setGroups([
        'profile'
    ]);
    $view->setContext($context);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for that kind of solution nifr, it's perfect ! Thank you.

Comment: I have a little problem with the paramconverter @nifr, the params added to the controller action change the url format such as the "Post $post" is now included in the url. Do you know can I only treat http_row_post_data and post method, it is to say, only deal with $request->getContent() where are my json payload

Comment: These seem to be two different issues, right? You can prevent controller arguments from showing up in the url by explicitly providing @Route or adding @NoRoute and putting that route's config directly into `routing.yml`. Action arguments are usually only added to the URL with implicit route/Url naming. Do you use that? I don't get the second part. You want to access the original JSON payload inside the controller action?

Comment: The problem is that paramconverter does not works if datas are not in the url...so I cannot use paramConverte :).